# What are the potential dangers of using this kind of reflection cheat in Python?

Tags: object-oriented, python, design-principles

In a program I'm working on, I need to do a substantial amount of real-time reflection in order to maintain a list of known "attributes" throughout the program structure (for use by a sort of "virtual programming assistant"). I came up with kind of a "cheaty" way of doing this (which I'm frankly kind of proud of), which is essentially akin to the following:

```
old_getattribute = obj.__getattribute__
def new_getattribute(self, attr):
    # various things...
    return old_getattribute(attr)
methods = {"__getattribute__" : new_getattribute}
obj.__class__ = type(              # Dynamically create a new class
    "%s" % obj.__class__.__name__, # whose name is _CLASS
    (obj.__class__, ),             # which subclasses CLASS
    methods)                       # and uses the new __getattribute__
```

Essentially, I dynamically create a new type that subclasses the original type, using a new `__getattribute__` method, and then reassign the object's internal `__class__` to this new dynamic type.

As amazed and happy as I am that this works (in Python >=3.6 at least), I'm still on the fence about using it. In my past python programming, any kind of modification of an object's magic methods from *outside* the object's `class` definition was pretty much forbidden, and yet here I am doing it twice in really messed up ways.

I would *like* to use it, as it would save me a ton of time instead of keeping track of individual objects in some "appropriate" manner and then continually checking them for changes, but I want to be sure that I'm not going to create any potential danger for the rest of the program.

So that's what I'm here to ask about. From a software architecture standpoint, how potentially dangerous is this method, and what pitfalls I may encounter getting this to work? I'm sure there are more than a few OOP/general programming principles I'm severely violating with this, but I'm willing to let those slide if this can be "managed".

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you basically want to inject code into existing objects that you can't (or don't want to) change directly?  Where are these objects coming from?  Are they coming from an unknown source?

Comment: @JimmyJames Yup thats the plan. Scary isn't it? They are indeed coming from an unknown source. What I like about this method though is that it essentially provides completely automatic, real-time tracking of changes in the object _when_ they occur. If an object's parameter gets set or updated or deleted, I don't need to constantly check the `__dict__` to see what's changed, the change is received immediately.

Comment: It's pretty slick but you are definitely going deep into the inner workings of Python.  I only have vague concerns but I'll ponder this some more.  Do all calls into this eventually pass-through to the original `__getattribute__`?

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes, unless program execution halts inbetween the call to the new `__getattribute__` and the call to the original `__getattribute__`. Otherwise it's essentially the same as just decorating `__getattribute__` dynamically. The reason I have to do the `obj.__class__ = type(...)` trick is because magic method lookups are performed on the class, and not on the instance, so setting `obj.__getattribute__ = decorator(obj.__getattribute__)` doesn't work.

Comment: @JimmyJames One major concern I just realized is that my injection code might get run in another process. I'm not sure what could go wrong if an object's attributes are modified while the object's `__class__` is being modified, but I can't really see any major problems that could occur. Also, as I'm the one running the injection code above, I can essentially control when it's called and ensure it's never called in a parallel process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `__getattribute__` you are deep in the bowel's of Python's object model. Things might work, but require a solid understanding. Also, some aspects might be implementation details of CPython and might fail on other implementations.

Things to consider:

- `__getattribute__` is insufficient to observe object modifications.
- `__getattribute__` will not be called when accessing special methods and possibly not when the object is accessed from within the Python interpreter.
- consider how this interacts with class member access.
- `__class__` might not be assignable.
- Changing the class breaks `type(x) is Foo` style checks.
- Metaclasses might prevent you from extending the original class.
- Specifying a `__getattribute__` implies a noticeable performance overhead. This might be a bit better if you implement it in C (provided you're using CPython).

From an OOP perspective, you're no longer working within the OO paradigm: instead of sending messages to other objects, you're intercepting the language's message dispatch implementation. That's arguable fine, and even has a name: Aspect-Oriented Programming. Python is flexible enough to pull this off implicitly, as you have shown. However, it might be vastly desirable to not instrument existing objects like this, but offer an API that makes it easier to make objects observable. Such an API would perhaps implement properties that can trigger a callback on access.

If you need to observe objects not during their normal execution but for some analysis, it might actually be easier to patch the CPython runtime with an extra hook. You might find some overlap with existing debugger hooks.

Comment: These are interesting points, thanks! The performance overhead is definitely concerning, seeing as how I would also technically have to overhead `__setattr__`, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, and even then I wouldn't be completely characterizing the changes in the object. For this application, I'm more or less only interested in the object's `__dict__` of _public values_, so it might be "good enough", but the other problems you mentioned are still concerning.